# Upgradingfrom django 1.11 to 2.0.8 python unittests became longer from 18 to 28 minutes

Tags: python, django, testing, backend, python-unittest

I am updating project which is build on `django 1.11` version to `django 2.0.8` version and I noticed that backend tests are taking much longer. It is taking now  28 minutes (instead of 18 minutes that was in `django 1.11`).

Do you have any ideas what may cause that problem, because it is crucial for the project to keep the time of the tests less.

Comment: Use `cProfile` to find out. `python -m cProfile -o stats.stat manage.py test`, then `python -m pstats stats.stat`, `sort time`, `stats 50`, and paste in the output.